# drop down list for country selection in j2me form

Tags: java-me

I want to make a form where then is login and password textfield.

Ans I want to add one dropdown list of country by which user can select the one of the country from that list.

How is it possible in j2me?

Comment: This is a poor question, it implies you have done no investigation about how to do this yourself, and also implies that you would be unlikely to make any sense of any response showing how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ChoiceGroup for this. See this demo application,

```
public class ChoiceGroup extends MIDlet 
{
   Display display=Display.getDisplay(this);

    public void startApp() 
    {
        Form form = new Form("Choice Form");
        //ChoiceGroup(label,type,elements,image)
        ChoiceGroup CoursePOP = new ChoiceGroup ("Pop Up choice", Choice.POPUP,
                               new String[] {"India", "Usa","UK"}, null);
        form.append(CoursePOP);
        display.setCurrent(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: i had done this choice group.But i think it is for checkbox.I want the list having array of 300-400 country.